# Unable to compile a C Program with gtk3 as gtk/gtk.h shows "No such file or directory"

Tags: c, gtk3, fatal-error

To compile a gtk helloworld program, I used this command on a Visual Studio Code terminal.

`gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) gtktest.c -o gtktest $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)`

it returns

```
gtktest.c:2:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
      |          ^~~~
```

but yet when I run
`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`
it returns

`-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/pango-1.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/glib-2.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/harfbuzz -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/freetype2 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/libpng16 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/fribidi -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/cairo -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/lzo -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/pixman-1 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/atk-1.0 -mms-bitfields`

and when I run `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` it returns

`-LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lhid -lwinspool -lcomctl32 -lcomdlg32 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl`

is there an issue with an install or am i doing something super wrong

Comment: Why not `gcc gtktest.c -o gtktest $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)` . On windows the path components can be problematic. Sometimes requiring quoting to work, though your use of the `'/'` looks correct. Then there is the issue if you are running within msys2. Make sure you are executing the command within your build environment as inside msys2 it may know nothing about `C:` (though I haven't tried this lately) Double check you have `C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/gtk-3.0 ` when you are in msys2.

Comment: I'm executing it in the visual studio code terminal, the one launched when you press CTRL + `, , and I tried running the command you gave, and it still referenced the same error as listed above. Funny enough when I try doing it via the build function in VSC, it gives me another error after I linked everything in pkg-config --cflags & --libs in the task.json for the builder in VSC, but the error states I have multiple main functions in my C file where i have not

Comment: I doubt that will work. The VSCode terminal will run compiled programs, but has nothing in the way of a configured build environment. It likely has only the ld_library_path set so the code can find shared object libs. The `pkg-config` output -- with canonical path names, really needs to be run in the fully configured build environment. I don't use VSCode as it always took 3-times as long to sort the `.json` files out as it did just to build from the command line. I suspect you need a few more tweaks to `tasks.json` so it puts the environment together correctly. That I can't help with.